# How do i duplicate and move a shape in Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am aware that I have asked a similar question in the past, and the answer worked great, but I just cant get my head around how to move this shape in this specific case.

Essentially there should be multiple rows of this shape, all next to each-other, and the next row down needs to be slightly offset, and then back and forth...

[image: Here is an image of what I have been trying to achieve]

I did try using `points[::x]` and `points[x::y]` to skip the values i didn't want changed, which is what I learnt from my previous question, but I cant figure out exactly how to write the code so that the shapes display as they do in the image. I have also been trying to use  `zip()` but since I have never used it before it did not work the way I wanted it to

Below is a part of the code detailing the starting shape which needs to be duplicated.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas()
canvas.pack()

points = [5, 10, 15, 5, 15, 5, 25, 5, 25, 5, 35, 10, 35, 10, 25, 20, 25, 20, 15, 20]
canvas.create_polygon(points, outline="white", fill="black", width=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you will have to doplicate list `points, modify values in `points` and use again `create_polygon()` to draw next object. And it may need to use `range(0, len(points), 2)` to work with values directly on list.

Comment: eventually you could create in the same place and get object ID - `object_id = canvas.create_polygon(...)` and later use ID to move it in new place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could duplicate and modify data in `points` to draw polygons in different places but it can be simpler to draw in the same place and get object ID

```
polygon_id = canvas.create_polygon(...)
```

and move it by some offset

```
canvas.move(polygon_id, offset_x, offset_y)
```

---

Full working code:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

points = [5, 10, 15, 5, 15, 5, 25, 5, 25, 5, 35, 10, 35, 10, 25, 20, 25, 20, 15, 20]

for offset_y in range(0, 300, 30):
    for offset_x in range(0, 300, 30):
        polygon_id = canvas.create_polygon(points, outline="white", fill="black", width=2)
        canvas.move(polygon_id, offset_x, offset_y)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Another example - with `row_offset`:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

points = [5, 10, 15, 5, 15, 5, 25, 5, 25, 5, 35, 10, 35, 10, 25, 20, 25, 20, 15, 20]

row_offset = 15 

for offset_y in range(0, 300, 15):
    for offset_x in range(0, 360, 30):
        polygon_id = canvas.create_polygon(points, outline="white", fill="black", width=2)
        canvas.move(polygon_id, offset_x+row_offset, offset_y)
        
    if row_offset == 15:
        row_offset = 0
    else:
        row_offset = 15

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: wow thank you so much! I had no idea there was a canvas.move() command, maybe I didnt notice it when looking through the different commands.

Comment: old and not complet documentation for [Canvas](https://web.archive.org/web/20190909161413/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.html) - for long time it was main source of information. It was removed few years ago but backup is still avaliable on `archive.org`